# Centrar div vertical y horizontalmente en la pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Tengo el siguiente `slider` de imágenes con un botón para adelante y otro para atrás para ir avanzando entre ellas.

Mi problema es el siguiente: No se cuadra bien el `slider` en el centro de la pantalla (en la horizontal y la vertical). ¿Cómo puedo centrarlo en la pantalla? (Tanto el `div` padre (`body`) como el `div` contenedor como también las flechas `< >`.

Código:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
.mySlides { display:none; }

#centrar {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
  
body { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" id="centrar">
    <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="5.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="6.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="7.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="8.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="9.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="10.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="11.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="12.jpg">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo de esta manera, en la clase centrar utiliza una `position:fixed;` y deja que los botones están a los costados de la página y que la imagen cubra el 100%.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
   showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
#centrar
{
 position: fixed; /* ó absolute */
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width:100%;
}
  .mySlides{
   width:100%;
  }

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: 0.6s ease; 
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" id="centrar">
   <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="5.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="6.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="7.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="8.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="9.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="10.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="11.jpg">
   <img class="mySlides" src="12.jpg">
      
   <button class="w3-button w3-black prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
   <button class="w3-button w3-black next" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes poner tu slider dentro de un div que utilice flexbox. Ejemplo:

```
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Usamos `100vw` y `100vh` para obtener el tamaño completo del viewport y luego centramos el contenido en ambos ejes con `justify-content` y `align-items`.

```
<div class="contenedor"> —tu slider aquí— </div>
```

También podrías utilizar `margin: auto` con flexbox en lugar de `justify-content` y `align-items`.

Nota: Tal vez deberías quitar la posición absoluta a `body`

Answer (score 2):

Para centrar un elemento en la vertical y la horizontal, [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) es de gran ayuda usado junto a los parámetros [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) y [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) ambos con valor `center`. Observa el siguiente snippet:

> Solo debes tener en cuenta que `flexbox` está disponible en Internet Explorer a partir de la versión 10 y aún así presenta varios problemas de compatibilidad con este browser.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  background: #EEE;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.elemento {
  background: #666;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="elemento"></div>
</div>
```

También puede que te sirva de ayuda, [este post](https://xprimiendo.com/alinear-elementos-verticalmente-css/) que escribí hace algún tiempo atrás.

Comment: El uso de flex-box es una gran recomendación para los navegadores actuales.

Answer (score 1):

Para centrar puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera con css:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Edita tu primera respuesta y agregas este código

Comment: Es diferente este método de centrar al que utilice en la otra respuesta.

Comment: Pero puedes agregarlo en tu primera respuesta que fue marcada.